# Add printer on Remote Windows Server as Local Printer

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, printing, printer, windows-server

I have a windows server that has a printer installed on it.  Currently if I want to print using it, I would RDP the server, copy the document over, and print it.

Would it be possible (for free) to add the remote printer as a local printer on my computer so it would do something such as automatically initiate the RDP connection, print and exit?

Note: I do NOT have admin rights on the server.

EDIT: This is an RDP server at my college so I would do not have any chance of getting admin privileges, and the printers are most likely under a different vlan or something else not visible to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

You have to share the printer on the Windows Server. I'm not 100% sure if this does work without admin rights - I have to research that.

How is the printer connected to the server? I doubt that it's USB? I guess it's through Ethernet (TCP/IP). In that case you only need the IP of the printer and can install it on your Client using that IP. The IP can be found under Ports (if I'm not wrong) at the Printer Properties on the server.

Comment: As I do not have admin rights, I am not able to see anything under ports besides the port name and description.
Also it is under printer properties, not preferences.

Comment: The printer is a network printer.

Comment: Can you open the registry? Let me boot up my working laptop to see how it's setup there. You should be able to find the port in the registry as long you can access it. (the registry on the server obviously)

Comment: I have registry access.

Comment: You can find the Location under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers`. Under Location you should find the IP of the printer

Comment: For the printers that even have a location (most of them don't even have the value) there is no data.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about the Location key. It should be the "Port"-Key. My last idea for today (I have to go to bed now -.-) would be to use an IP Scanner like "Angry IP Scan" to search your subnet for all devices - most likely including your printer =) Also depending on your printer there are tools to search the network for those printers (Kyocera and HP do have that - the Kyocera Net Viewer even shows me some HP printers http://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.de/index/document_solutions/network_device_management/netviewer_web/KMnetViewer_Download.html)

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't provide you the perfect solution... I can't replicate your case, because I've got admin privileges on our printserver. Can't you maybe ask your administrator for the IP? Or even easier, if he could share the printer on the printserver? =)

Comment: This is an RDP server at my college so I would do not have admin privileges, and the printers are most likely under a different vlan not visible to the outside world.

Comment: Ok. But if it's your colleague he should be able to provide you either the IP, or share the printer?! I guess asking him might be a thousand times easier than trying to find the IP somethere in the registry.